# Does PouchDB suppress multiple identical replications?

Tags: pouchdb

If I make a call to `PouchDB.sync`, specifying `retry: true` and `live: true`, and subsequently repeat that call, does PouchDB:

1. reuse the first request for continuous replication and ignore the second request?
2. cancel the first request and create the second as a replacement?
3. attempt to maintain more than one apparently identical live replication

Even if 1. is the case, are there any dangers I should be aware of making multiple calls like this?

The context is a node-red application. I'm currently explicitly calling `sync` on a 15 minute timer, but without `live` and `retry`.

I *could* just inject a single call at the start of the flow in question and specify `live` and `retry` but I'm wary - irrationally superstitious even - of just leaving PouchDB to it without some sort of periodic manual attempt.

ETA: as suggested (and as I should really have done in the first place) I've tested by attempting to create multiple continuous replications - one every 5 minutes over a > 24hr period. There was no discernible leak of resources, and the source and destination DBs in question didn't appear to suffer any ill effects.

So I conclude that it's reusing where the sync appears to be identical, but in the process, I've also convinced myself that a single continuous replication at startup, punctuated by a non-continuous replication every hour or so is as much belt and braces as I need.

Comment: Should be easy to test to see how it behaves. But my guess is that you'll end up with redundant sync processes, which you probably don't want.